# How do I upload a Document file(no video or picture) from iOS to my website?

Tags: javascript, php, ios, file-upload

I want to upload the document files in the iPhone to my home page.  (PDF, txt...)
Was referring to this web site (http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/KjEHg), but I can upload only photo(and video).

If you know how to do the upload in some way, please tell me.
(It couldn't have to be a Web Language.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is very irrelevant question, Second, it is iOS problem, no problem with code on website. You might wanna look in the app store for FTP apps, like FTP on the Go and sync with you web-server you host your website.